# Python Pandas Threading reads read_fwf

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie-ish python/pandas user here.  I've been playing with using chunksize arg in read_fwf and iterating value_counts of variables.  I wrote a function to pass args such as the fileiterator and variables to parse and count.  I was hoping to parallelize this function and be able to read 2 files at the same time into the same function.
It does appear to work... However, I'm getting unexpected slow downs.  The threads finish same time but one seems to be slowing the other down (IO bottleneck?).  I'm getting faster times by running the functions sequentially rather than parallel (324 secs Vs 172 secs). Ideas? I'm I executing this wrong?  I've tried multiprocess but startmap errors that I can't pickle the fileiterator (output of read_fwf).

```
testdf1=pd.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer='200k.dat',header=None,colspecs=wlist,names=nlist,dtype=object,na_values=[''],chunksize=1000)    
testdf2=pd.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer='200k2.dat',header=None,colspecs=wlist,names=nlist,dtype=object,na_values=[''],chunksize=1000)

def tfuncth(df,varn,q,*args):
    td={}
    for key in varn.keys():
        td[key]=pd.Series()
    for rdf in df:
        if args is not None:
            for arg in args:
                rdf=eval(f"rdf.query(\"{arg}\")")
        for key in varn.keys():
            ecode=f'rdf.{varn[key]}.value_counts()'
            td[key]=pd.concat([td[key],eval(ecode)])
            td[key]=td[key].groupby(td[key].index).sum()
    for key in varn.keys():
        td[key]=pd.DataFrame(td[key].reset_index()).rename(columns={'index':'Value',0:'Counts'}).assign(Var=key,PCT=lambda x:round(x.Counts/x.Counts.sum()*100,2))[['Var','Value','Counts','PCT']]
    q.put(td)

  bands={
        '1':'A',
        '2':'B',
        '3':'C',
        '4':'D',
        '5':'E',
        '6':'F',
        '7':'G',
        '8':'H',
        '9':'I'
    }
    vdict={
        'var1':'e1270.str.slice(0,2)',
        'var2':'e1270.str.slice(2,3)',
        'band':'e7641.str.slice(0,1).replace(bands)'
    }

    my_q1=queue.Queue()
    my_q2=queue.Queue()
    thread1=threading.Thread(target=tfuncth,args=(testdf1,vdict,my_q1,flter1))
    thread2=threading.Thread(target=tfuncth,args=(testdf2,vdict,my_q2))
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
```

UPDATE:

After much reading This is the conclusion I've came too.  This is extremely simplified conclusion I'm sure so if someone knows otherwise please inform me.

1. Pandas is not a fully multi-thread friendly package

   - Apparently there’s a package called ‘dask’ that is and it         replicates a lot of pandas functions.  So I’ll be looking into that.
2. Python is not truly a multi-threading compatible language in many
   cases

   - Python is bound by its compiler.  In pure python, its interpreted and bound by the GIL for only execution of one thread at a time

     - Multiple threads can be spun off but will only be able to parallel non-cpu bound functions.
     - My code is wrapped with IO and CPU.  The simple IO is probably running parallel but getting held up waiting on the processor for execution.
     - I plan to test this out by writing IO only operations and attempting threading.
   - Python can be compiled with different compilers that don’t have a global interpreter lock (GIL) on threads.

     - Thus packages such as ‘dask’ can utilize multi-threading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to get this to work and fix my problems by using the multiprocessing package.  I ran into two issues.
1) multiprocessing package is not compatible with Juypter Notebook

and

2) you can't pickle a handle to a pandas reader (multiprocessing pickles objects passed to the processes).

I fixed 1 by coding outside the Notebook environment and I fixed 2 by passing in the arguments needed to open a chunking file to each process and had each process start their own chunk read.

After doing those two things I was able to get a 60% increase in speed over sequential runs.